# natbib - Citation in English and German

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, babel

I am writing a document, which combines a German chapter (the intro) with several English chapters (the main document).

Hence I would like to use the `natbib` in the intro, to provide a citation which is consistent with... Author 1 und Author 2 (Year) and afterwards the English version.

I.e., the same article would for instance be quoted like this:

> Intro: Fama und French (2000)
>   Main Part: Fama and French (2000)

I read a couple of articles in this list and asked Google for help. But did not manage to find a solution, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Will there also be two separate bibliographies, or just one? Have you chosen the bibliography style file?

Comment: Yes, there will be two separate bibliographies, i.e. like in a edited book. In fact,I use the bibunits packacke to generate separate bibliographies.

Comment: No the \& is not feasible. I think I need the "und" and "and" - Style. For more than 3 authors it is the same in both languages (et al.).

Comment: Good news that you're using the `bibunits` package. It lets you use different style files for each of the bibliographies. Use whatever style file (e.g., `plainnat.bst`) you need to use for the main bibliography, create a copy of that file (naming it geplainnat.bst, say), change the function that provides the `and` conjunction so that it produces `und`, and use `geplainnat` for the bibliography of the intro chapter.

Comment: Thx. That's what I have already tried. I think latex doesn't get the connection to the new bst. I use it this way: `\begin{bibunit}[chicago] \putbib[thebibtexfile]`. I am also using the koma-script package and since I have a master-file from a colleage, using the same packages like me and employing the same commands, I wonder why it works in the master and not for my document... what a mess... thx Mico anyway.

Comment: Did you (a) specify different style files for the separate bibunits and (b) run latex on the full document, bibtex separately on each bibunit, and latex *twice more* on the full document?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, your description solves the issue. It was my fault. I just managed to check that natbib is different from chicago. For German users, here is another link fot that issue [http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?t=68001] thx Mico, Problem solved

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. I'm going to propose to close this question because the issue seems to have arisen from some (understandable) confusion rather than some inherent problem .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it arises from confusion over the uses of (a) the `natbib` citation management package and (b) the `chicago` bibliography style.